CocoaPods Error Installing `BoringSSL-GRPC` during `pod install` – RPC failed, curl 92 HTTP/2 stream not closed cleanly
I’m trying to run pod install for my Flutter project, but I keep running into an error while installing BoringSSL-GRPC. Here's the full error message:
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update     

Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '11.2.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '11.2.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '11.2.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '11.2.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Downloading dependencies
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.36)

[!] Error installing BoringSSL-GRPC
[!] /opt/homebrew/bin/git clone https://github.com/google/boringssl.git /var/folders/_j/y2bmb3f57vv3ngw1nfzqs_zr0000gn/T/d20241010-83288-6dfggb --template=

Cloning into '/var/folders/_j/y2bmb3f57vv3ngw1nfzqs_zr0000gn/T/d20241010-83288-6dfggb'...
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 5 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
error: 10 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

Manually cloning the boringssl repository into the directory that CocoaPods uses for temporary files:
git clone https://github.com/google/boringssl.git/var/folders/_j/y2bmb3f57vv3ngw1nfzqs_zr0000gn/T/d20241010-72238-37tuvs

Shallow clone of the repository:
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/google/boringssl.git/var/folders/_j/y2bmb3f57vv3ngw1nfzqs_zr0000gn/T/d20241010-72238-37tuvs

Increasing Git buffer size using:
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
Running pod install with arch -x86_64 to ensure compatibility with my Apple Silicon Mac:
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
Despite all of this, I keep getting the same error. My internet connection is stable, and I’ve tried multiple times to install this dependency, but I keep running into the RPC failed issue.
Has anyone experienced this or knows how to resolve this issue? I’d appreciate any suggestions!

Please include the text of your error in your post, not a picture of it.

Try to add custom script to your Podfile to remove unwanted compiler flags for BoringSSL-GRPC.
Goto -> ios/Podfile
Add the following code in post_install block
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

    # Additional logic for BoringSSL-GRPC
    if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
      target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
        if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
          flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
          # Remove the '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' flag
          flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
          file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

Then try to run "pod repo update && pod install" command.

I'll try this. Thanks!

It works, thanks!
